# Order of transactions returned by Braintree API

Tags: ruby, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, braintree

When retrieving the transactions for a Braintree::Customer, the ResourceCollection returned seems to be ordered by decreasing created_at. Is it safe to assume this will always be the case?

If one wanted a different order, could that be specified via the the optional options hash parameter? Is there documentation of what can be provided as options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you want more detailed help than we can give on Stack Overflow, please get in touch with [our support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support).</sub>

Yes, they'll always be returned in that order. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be documented under [customer details](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/customers/details), possibly because the `transactions` method isn't supported in all of our client libraries. We'll check it out and add it to our docs if possible -- thanks for bringing it to our attention.

The `options` parameter is not actually used; it is left over from the original, non-threadsafe version of the library for backwards compatibility reasons.

If you want a subset of transactions, you can use [transaction search](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/search), but when getting the transactions from the customer object, they will always be sorted by `created_at`.